# How do I convert V8 objects to pointers?

Tags: c++, node.js, native

I'm writing a Node application (in TS) that needs to be interfaced with some native library.

I have a library (written in C) - let's consider it's a blackbox - and I'm writing a wrapper using NAN. The library native interface can be simplified into a following functions:

```
typedef void (*got_message_reply_cb)(context ctx, void * priv, struct X * the_reply);

context lib_connect();
bool lib_send_message(context ctx, message msg, got_message_reply_cb callback, void * priv);
```

I believe this is pretty straight-forward to understand.

So, I'm trying to wrap that black-box native library into something like:

```
class TheLibrary : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
    Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> target);
    SendMessage(...)
}
```

And then to javascript object like:

```
class TheLibrary {
    SendMessage(message: whatever, callback: (reply) => void); // or return promise, doesn't matter
}
```

How to do the actual handling of the callback in the NAN C++ module? I need to somehow pass the callback (represented probably by `Local<Function>` - which have, if I understand it correctly, limited scope) as a pointer to the function and then retrieve it back. How to do that? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this post will answer your question: https://nodeaddons.com/building-an-asynchronous-c-addon-for-node-js-using-nan/

Comment: Will the callback be called from another thread? If so it gets a littlebit complicated because you're forced to access JS stuff within the UV default thread. If its in the same thread you could may allocate a persistent object of the callback on the  heap and pass it as priv pointer . As a collback you have to write a function which will takes the priv pointer casts it back to the persistent function and call it

Comment: See: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: JavaScript and Java do not have pointers, both have references.  C++ also has references, whilst you cannot use pointers in JavaScript or Java, there really isn't much different between a reference and a pointer apart from the syntax and the use of "&" and "*".

Comment: To put WolverinDEV’s point differently: do you need each call to `SendMessage` to be asynchronous in JavaScript?  If not, I don’t think you even need to heap-allocate anything.

Comment: I suggest you consider using the new [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) instead. I am in the process of porting several NAN type addons to N-API because they need constant maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

The high level answer is that you don't pass the JS callback function directly, but pass in a pointer to a function that somehow has your JS callback as a context value (in your example the `priv` parameter).

So for your case you write something like this:

```
void TheLibraryCallback(context ctx, void *instance, struct X *the_reply) {
    ((TheLibrary*)instance)->callback(ctx, the_reply);
}
```

In your `TheLibrary` you add a method `void callback(context ctx, struct X * the_reply)` that handles the callback. You call your library like this: `lib_send_message(ctx, msg, TheLibraryCallback, this);` with `this` being a `TheLibrary` instance.

So how do you call back the JS callback in your callback method? With `nan` you will have to make sure you are back in the main thread. There are [examples](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/tree/master/examples/async_pi_estimate) out there, but I would suggest that you use the new [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) instead. The [AsyncWorker](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/async_worker.md) helps with the boilerplate that you need to do to call the callback in the main thread.